# What is the connection between Iteratees and FRP?

Tags: haskell, frp, conduit, loops, haskell-pipes

It seems to me that there is a strong connection between the two ideas. My guess is that FRP could be implemented in terms of Iteratees if there would be a way to express arbitrary graphs with Iteratees. But afaik they only support chain-like structures.

Could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the other way around.  There is a strong connection between AFRP and stream processing.  In fact AFRP *is* a form of stream processing, and you can use the idiom to implement something very similar to pipes:

```
data Pipe m a b =
    Pipe {
      cleanup :: m (),
      feed    :: [a] -> m (Maybe [b], Pipe m a b)
    }
```

That's an extension of wire categories as found in Netwire.  It receives the next chunk of input and returns Nothing when it stops producing.  Using this a file reader would have the following type:

```
readFile :: (MonadIO m) => FilePath -> Pipe m a ByteString
```

Pipe is a family of applicative functors, so to apply a simple function to the stream elements you could just use *fmap*:

```
fmap (B.map toUpper) . readFile
```

For your convenience it's also a family of profunctors.

The most interesting feature is that this is a family of Alternative functors.  That allows you to route streams around and allow multiple stream processors to "try" before giving up.  This can be extended to a full-fledged parsing library that can even use some static information for optimization purposes.

Comment: Ah, I was about to post something similar, but I will defer to the expertise of someone who actually wrote an AFRP library. :]

Comment: It seems that using (A)FRP I wouldn't be restricted to an acyclic graph structure, is this true?

Comment: It is not clear to me from your answer what if any aspects of AFRP can not be implemented in terms or the recent stream possessing libraries conduit/pipes?

Answer (score 13):

You can implement a limited form of FRP using stream processors.  For example, using the `pipes` library, you might define a source of events:

```
mouseCoordinates :: (Proxy p) => () -> Producer p MouseCoord IO r
```

... and you might similarly define a graphical handler that takes mouse coordinates and updates a cursor on a canvas:

```
coordHandler :: (Proxy p) => () -> Consumer p MouseCoord IO r
```

Then you would hook up the mouse events to the handler using composition:

```
>>> runProxy $ mouseCoordinates >-> coordHandler
```

And it would run just the way you expect.

Like you said, this works well for a single chain of stages, but what about more arbitrary topologies?  Well, it turns out that since the central `Proxy` type of `pipes` is a monad transformer, you can model any arbitrary topology just by nesting proxy monad transformers on top of themselves.  For example, here is how you would zip two input streams:

```
zipD
 :: (Monad m, Proxy p1, Proxy p2, Proxy p3)
 => () -> Consumer p1 a (Consumer p2 b (Producer p3 (a, b) m)) r
zipD () = runIdentityP $ hoist (runIdentityP . hoist runIdentityP) $ forever $ do
    a <- request ()               -- Request from the outer Consumer
    b <- lift $ request ()        -- Request from the inner consumer
    lift $ lift $ respond (a, b)  -- Respond to the Producer
```

This behaves like a curried function.  You partially apply it to each input sequentially and you can then run it when it is fully applied.

```
-- 1st application
p1 = runProxyK $ zipD   <-< fromListS [1..]

-- 2nd application
p2 = runProxyK $ p2     <-< fromListS [4..6]

-- 3rd application
p3 = runProxy  $ printD <-< p3
```

It runs just the way you expect:

```
>>> p3
(1, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 6)
```

This trick generalizes to any topology.  You can find a lot more details about this in [Control.Proxy.Tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html) in the "Branches, zips, and merges" section.  In particular, you should check out the `fork` combinator it uses as an example, which lets you split a stream into two outputs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is true of all sane iteratee libraries.  Oleg used it some time ago.  I'm not sure why nobody ever seems to remember that it's possible; the technique is very useful.

Comment: @JohnL That is why you have to preach it!  Not everybody knows what Oleg did.

Comment: Even people who know what Oleg did often don't understand it.  Sadly I'm frequently in this group, at least at first...